# Quando si dice appropriato e quando i suoi sinonimi?

Tags: nouns

Questa parola ha molti sinonimi come

Apposito
Adeguata

E tanti altri quando lo tradurro in Google

Ma non so veramente quale usare dove

[image]

Comment: Per cominciare, da' un'occhiata alle voci relative su un dizionario monolingue, che danno una definizione completa, esempi e così via: [appropriato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appropriato/), [apposito](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/apposito/) etc.

Comment: Probabilmente anche un buon dizionario bilingue è sufficiente per questa domanda...

Comment: Hai sprecato un'imperdibile occasione di usare il titolo *quando è appropriato "appropriato"*. :)

Answer (score 3):

Buona domanda, vediamo se riesco a fare un poca di chiarezza, dato che l'argomento confonde anche me, che sono madrelingua...

Abbiamo le seguenti parole (tralasciando parole oscure come acconcio):

**Appropriato**
Usato per indicare qualcosa che sta bene con lo scopo o contesto di cui si parla. A volte indica un certo senso di necessità, come nel primo esempio sotto.

> Per un colloquio di lavoro è appropriato mettersi una camicia.
>   È un vestito appropriato per l'occasione.

**Adeguato**
Dà l'idea di qualcosa di sufficiente per lo scopo di cui si sta parlando.

> Il telefono era economico, ma adeguato alle necessità di mia madre.

**Apposito**
Dà l'idea di un oggetto costruito per uno scopo preciso.

> Per smontare il cambio della bicicletta serve un atrezzo apposito.

**Adatto**
Molto simile ad appropriato. Non ha un senso di necessità.

> È un vestito adatto per l'occasione.

**Opportuno**
Molto simile ad appropriato, ma rafforza ancora di più il senso di necessitá.

> È opportuno dare del lei al professore.

**Pertinente**
Usato per lo più per indicare un accordo con un argomento (il contrario di off-topic).

> La domanda/ L'intervento è pertinente.

**Consono**
Indica l'appartenenza ad una certa situazione.

> Comportati in modo consono!

**Azzeccato**
Dà l'idea che la scelta fatta era quella giusta tra molte possibili.

> Ho azzeccato il momento giusto per parlare con il mio supervisore.
>   Gli antipasti erano proprip azzeccati.

Certamente la differenza per alcune di queste parole non è così grossa e si possono usare intercambiabilmente, in base al contesto.

Comment: Per piacere, in questo sito è importante curare l'ortografia: potresti rileggere  e correggere quello che scrivi (a cominciare da “dà” come terza persona del verbo “dare”), per piacere?

Comment: @DaG Grazie, corretto, non sono mai stato un maestro di ortografia...

Answer (score 0):

**Appropriato** è sinonimo di **adeguato**.

La tua traduzione su Google è giusta =)

Io userei tutti e due senza distinzione, come in inglese.

Comment: Marcelo, questa non è una vera risposta, perché l'OP conosce già la parola “adeguato”, ma vuole sapere, dei vari sinonimi, quale usare dove. Inoltre ti chiederei di prestare più attenzione a quello che scrivi: chi viene qui lo fa proprio per imparare l'italiano. Si dice “sinonimo *di*”, non “*da*”. E altrove scrivi “pò” anziché “po'” e così via.